# Disabling .NET library methods to encourage the use of business layer functions instead

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, intellisense

I was wondering if .NET has any methods that are capable of preventing use of other methods in imported reference files.

My reasoning is for security and preventing developers from using raw functions instead of functionality written by the applications business layer framework.

Example is I don't want any developers using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand() function to protect against the ability to introduce an SQL injection problem.

If the function was native, I could make it obsolete as a warning or remove it, but how do I do this to libraries where I potentially want to use other functionality inside them.

Can this be done in code to protect the application, or is the only way to extend intellisense / add a rule into a tool such as ReSharper?

Interested in knowing what people have done for this kind of thing.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked into writing a Roslyn Analyzer or FxCop (Code Analysis) rule? They can ultimately be suppressed by developers, but would serve as a good starting point.